# How to remove the ULR, special character and @ User in text by python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4vYB.png)

The 'text' content in this table includes URL, Emoji, and @ User which is not useful for our text analysis so how can I remove them?

Comment: You could regex library to find those elements and remove them, could you show a code that you have made to extract those information?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but I'd start by looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html